# Swift- How can I have a button refresh each time it's hit?

Tags: button, if-statement, swift, label

I can't seem to figure out how to have a function block repeated when a UIButton is pressed in swift. Here's what I have:

```
class CoinFlip: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!
    var randomNumber = (Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))
    @IBAction func tossButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if randomNumber == 0 {
        resultLabel.text = "Heads!"
        }
        else if randomNumber == 1 {
        resultLabel.text = "Tails!"
        }
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed in the app, it picks a random number. If I hit it again, it displays the same number. What can I do so each time I hit the button it refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var randomNumber = 0

    @IBAction func tossButton(sender: UIButton) {
        randomNumber  = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
        if randomNumber == 0 {
            resultLabel.text = "Heads!"
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "Tails!"
        }
    }
```

you can also create a read-only computed property as follow:

> Read-Only Computed Properties
>
> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a
>   read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always
>   returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be
>   set to a different value.
>
> NOTE
>
> You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed
>   properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.
>
> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces:

```
    var headsTails:Bool {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) == 1 ? true : false
    }

    if headsTails  {
        println("Heads")
    } else {
        println("Tails")
    }

    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
    println(headsTails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick code, hope it helps:

```
class CoinFlip: UIViewController {

    var randomNumber: Int?

    @IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func tossButton(sender: UIButton) {
        guard (randomNumber != nil) else {
            randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) // picks a number
            resultLabel.text = ""                     // removes the old result
            return
        }

        // Displays the number
        resultLabel.text = randomNumber == 0 ? "Heads!" : "Tails!"
        randomNumber = nil
    }
}
```